# Find a simple path from S to T in a directed graph so that the product of its weights is maximum

Tags: graphs, shortest-path, directed-graphs

I'm looking for an algorithm that finds a simple path from S to T in a directed graph (which might have cycles) so that the product of edge weights in the path is maximum. All the edge weights of the graph are larger than zero. For any pair of nodes, there might be more than 1 edge.

I thought of the following approach. First I invert all the edge weights, i.e $w_{new} = \frac{1}{w}$. Then I run a shortest-path algorithm such as Dijkstra against the new graph. Is doing this ok? If not then which algorithm I can use for my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is NP-hard by a reduction from the Hamiltonian-path problem.

If all edge weights are set to some constant $c>1$ and $P$ is a simple path from $s$ to $t$ that maximizes the product of the edge weights, you have that the number of edges in $P$ is $n-1$ (where $n$ is the number of vertices of the graph) if and only if the input graph contains a Hamiltonian path from $s$ to $t$.

Notice that the Hamiltonian path problem remains NP-Hard even if you fix the endpoints.

Comment: In my problem, an edge weight might be $< 1$. So the optimal path might not travel through all the nodes.

Comment: I'm reducing **from** Hamiltonian path **to** your problem, so as long as the edge weights **can** be greater than $1$ the reduction works.

Comment: If the requirement that the path must be simple is removed, will the problem not be NP-hard anymore?

Comment: If the path is not required to be simple and there is a cycle having edge weights with an overall product larger than $1$, then there is no path of maximum overall weight. If no such cycle exists, the problem is solvable in polynomial time by finding a shortest path in the graph in which each generic edge $e$ having weight $w_e$ is reweighted as $- \log w_e$. To answer your question: the problem with the requirement removed is NP-hard if and only if P=NP.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\max \prod_{i}p_i\iff \max \sum_{i}\log p_i,\,p_i>0
$$

So it's nearly equal to ask ["single source longest path"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem), which is NP-hard in most graphs. There is a Polynomial solution on DAG. [algorithm](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-longest-path-directed-acyclic-graph/)

Here is origin answer, I preserve it to help others avoid similar mistakes :-( $\min$ and $\max$ are totally different!

Why not try to take logarithm of every edge's weight?

$$
\min \prod_{i}p_i\iff \min \sum_{i}\log p_i,\,p_i>0
$$

But $\log p_i$ might give a negative cycle(e.g. every edge's weight < 1). Now it becomes another problem: simple-path, and [this](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/17462/finding-the-shortest-path-in-the-presence-of-negative-cycles) shows it's NP-hard.

But if $\forall p_i > 1$, you can solve it with dijkstra after preprocessing above. Because for graph without negative edge, dijkstra will always output a simple shortest path.

Comment: That's not a counterexample. My reduction is **from** Hamiltonian path, **to** the problem at hand. What would be the instance of Hamiltonian path that resulted in this weighted graph (there can be none since in my reduction all edge weights are set to the same value)?

Comment: @Steven I figured out what's wrong. I use $\min$ mistakenly while the problem is $\max$. My initial though is "min and max is just a pair of dual problem", but after searching, I understand it's really different. Your reduction is simple and nice. I will elaborate that in my answer later.